# CMake: DLLs Missing

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm new to CMake and have been experiencing endless errors.

main.cpp

```
#include <tox/tox.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Tox* tox = tox_new(NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

Project(toxtest)

add_library(toxcore SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(toxcore PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/c-toxcore/include"
    IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/c-toxcore/_build/Debug/toxcore.lib"
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/c-toxcore/_build/Debug/toxcore.dll"
)

set(BINARY_NAME "toxtest-bin")
add_executable(${BINARY_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${BINARY_NAME} PUBLIC toxcore)
```

Introduction:
My C++ executable depends on a C-library called toxcore, toxcore depends on two other C-libraries called pthread-win32 and libsodium.
I have compiled the toxcore library with the following flags, to solve a **unresolved external symbol** error (Not sure if this is the right way):

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS=TRUE -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=TRUE
```

I build my executable successfully but now it complains about missing DLLs: toxcore.dll, libsodium.dll, pthreadVC2.dll

I dumped the DLLs into the directory with the executable, and now I got Application Error:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

How do I this properly? I want to solve the Application Error, and let the executable find the DLLs in their respective directories.

I have looked through and tried Stack Overflow answers which were not sufficient in detail/clarity for a beginner like me. I need a tailored answer and to be told if my steps are in line with the current best practices.

Comment: Are you mixing and matching 32 and 64-bit dlls?

Comment: Are these dlls in the system PATH?

Comment: ok I "fixed" it by changing the toxcore dependencies to 32 bit DLL's (pthread and libsodium), can a 32-bit library be used with a 64-bit executable? Also I still need to figure out how to find the DLL's